# Trigger happy.js validation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, callback

[jQuery validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) is kind of bloated for my purpose, so I found [Happy.js](http://happyjs.com/). Unfortunately, the validation is only triggered when using a Submit-button, which I don't have. jQuery-validation offered a function "form()" to trigger the validation programmatically, so I tried to implement the function into Happy.js – without any success. I found a happy-callback implementation ([commit](https://github.com/mrbox/Happy.js/commit/577f942eff4177559db0b8017c4830a9bd375856)), but this doesn't work either.

Some code (**updated**):

```
$('#someFormSubmit').click(function() {
  $('#someForm').submit();
});
$('#someForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.post('/some', $('#someForm').serialize())
    .success(function(response) {});
});
$("#someForm").isHappy({
  fields: {
    '#name': {
      required: true,
      message: "Hello"
    },
  },
  testMode: true,
  unHappy: function () { alert("hello"); },
});
```

There's no alert from the callbacks and 'happy' is always true, when it should be false.

The form is in a twitter-bootstrap modal box. Due to the separation of modal-body and modal-footer there's only a link .btn to submit, but not a proper input type=submit.

Any solutions?

Comment: `isHappy` sets up the validation, not runs it.  It should be ran when the page is loaded, not on the click event.

Comment: Right. That worked for jquery-validation. Changed it, but still no success. :(

Comment: Try to put `$("#someForm").isHappy({` before `$('#someForm').submit(function(event) {`.

Comment: Yes, it's finally working. I'll update the question with the code ...

Comment: Make sure to keep the original code in the question, so it still makes sense.  Better yet, select the answer that helped, or answer your own question.  The solutions should really stay out of the questions, that's what answers are for.

Comment: Great, my edit on benekastah's answer never got accepted, which contained the complete working code. I just wanted to compare the code as something didn't work. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Remember to do all your happy validation stuff first, to ensure that jQuery
// fires off the events in the correct order.
$("#yourForm").isHappy({
  // your validation config
});

$("#yourForm").submit(function (event) {
  // This line prevents the form from actually being submitted
  event.preventDefault();

  // You can then define your actions however you like
  $.post({
    // your config here
  });
});

// When it's time to "submit" the form, it's easy
$("#yourForm").submit();
```

I haven't tested this with happy.js, but it *should* trigger validation as well.

**Update**: Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsLvG/9/) for this. It demonstrates that it is working (although if you check the fiddle, you will see a few modifications to this code). I don't know why the fields aren't validating on blur, though. That's supposed to work out of the box with happy.js, so you might want to post an issue to the author if you are having that problem.

Comment: jQuery should trigger events in the order they are declared.  So, happy's event handler should run, then this one, then `event.preventDefault` should stop submission.  So, it *should* work. :-)

Comment: @Rocket Good point. Added comment to make sure that the happy.js stuff is explicitly done first.

Comment: AJAX $.post() works fine with your example, but validation is not triggered.

Comment: Ok, validation not gets triggered and the unHappy-callback alerts. But the form is submitted also on invalid data.

Comment: @Patrick Check the link to the jsfiddle in my update. It works there.

Comment: Throw in `event.stopPropagation();` too if using Zepto. See: https://github.com/fgnass/Happy.js/commit/4e23e8daf0686016be90623dc441ca0cedc37b3e

Comment: I like the fiddle better, especially the chaining of the two calls.

Comment: Yes your post was great help for me too. Not sure why required validation is not triggered on blur but only on submit...

Answer (score 1):

From [HappyJS](http://happyjs.com/)

> *Happy.js will now validate individual fields on blur events and all fields on submit.*

The validation on blur events isn't enough?

Try to write your HTML code and what you're doing with JS into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), will be easier to get help with it.

But, if you just want to activate the validation when some button/element is clicked, just set the jQuery selector to the variable `submitButton` in the parameters from happy function

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `submitButton` option?

From the official documentation at http://happyjs.com/:

`submitButton (string)`: If you pass jQuery selector to this the form will be validated when that item is clicked instead of on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Happy.js registers a submit handler, so if you need to trigger it programmatically you should be able to just trigger submit with jQuery, no?

```
$(form).submit()
```

Comment: Not if you want to use $.post for an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form').isHappy({
    when: "blur keyup"
});
```

This syntax works for the current version of Happy.js.